# Modeling Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, circles, combinations

I encountered the following problem:

"We are given n points in the plane such that no three are collinear and no four lie on the same circle.
How many circles are there that contain three of these points?"

Now I attempted to solve it and I ended up having 3 circles as the answer. I got there by actually drawing possibilities. However, I feel it's wrong.
Any correction or explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure about your question. The number of circles depends on how the points are drawn. Do you mean what is the most number of circles that can contain 3 of the points? Or the least number?

Comment: 3 of the points, not the least.

Comment: But...any three (non-collinear) points lie on a unique circle. So the number of circles is just the number of ways to choose $3$ points from your set. Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: I think we both might have a problem understanding the question. I copied it as I've found it. But I think they mean to ask the number of circles that can be drawn using any 3 points of these n points without a fourth point on the same circle. Maybe the answer will be in terms of n?

Comment: Well, according to my reading of the question the answer is $\binom n3$.  Any three (unordered) points from your collection determine a circle and no two of these circles coincide.

Comment: So nC3. There's no way to get rid of the variable n

Comment: Certainly not.  As the collection grows you expect more and more possible circles.

Comment: Okay thanks. Put it as an answer please so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key geometric fact here is that any $3$ non-collinear points determine a unique circle.  To see this, note that the center has to be equidistant from each of your three points, hence must lie on each of the three perpendicular bisectors of the segments made by taking any $2$ of the points.  Non-collinearity ensures that no two of these perpendicular bisectors are parallel,   To see that all three meet at a single point (the center of the circle we seek):  consider two bisectors, $P_{A,B}$ and $P_{B,C}$.  As they are not parallel they meet at a point $O$.  Now, since $O\in P_{A,B}$ we have $d(O,A)=d(O,B)$.  Similarly $d(O,B)=d(O,C)$  It follows that $d(O,A)=d(O,C)$ whence we conclude that $O\in P_{A,C}$.

Therefore, we get a circle of the type you want by taking any three distinct points from your collection. No two of these circles coincide (for if they did then we'd have at least $4$ points from your collection on a single circle, contrary to assumption).

Therefore the number of circles of the type you want equals the number of ways we can choose three points from your collection.   Hence the answer is $\binom n3$.